# Flash player security settings

Tags: security, flash, twilio

I am using twilo client in one of my apps and it is showing following popup when I click on call button
[image: Flash Security settings]

But I want to show the following pop up which is lot simpler and seems less cumbersome
[image: Flash Security settings]

Is there a way to control which pop up comes on the screen? I have read some documentation of adobe but their configuration files live in users computer which ofcourse can not be changed by a website.
Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: this popup it's a native/core flash player popup you can not edit or customize it

Comment: @mgraph i thought so...:( Feel free to convert your comment into answer

Comment: @wvxvw Well the ICON with an "Eye"(the selected tab in the first screen shot and icon near allow button in the second one) makes me think that they are the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, those dialogs are native Flash Player dialogs. The request domain is drawn from the domain that the swf is loaded in, and it must be for security reasons. The only way around this is to have the request come from a swf which is loaded from a "friendlier" domain.

Sounds like something that Twilio would need to address, not you. Perhaps you can bug them on their forum or such?